# configuring dynamic url's in router

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter. Basically what I want is to remove the Controller name (*Home*) from the url.

Those urls look like:

```
http://localhost/mechanicly/Home
http://localhost/mechanicly/Home/about
http://localhost/mechanicly/Home/contactus
```

now there are two ways I can remove the *Home* controller:

1. static definition of every url inside route:

   ```
   $route['about'] = "Home/about";
   $route['contactus'] = "Home/contactus";
   ```
2. I can use call backs in routes in Codeigniter:

   ```
   $route['(.+)'] = function ( $param ) {

     if( strpos( $param, "Admin" ) !== false ) {
       echo $param;
       return "Admin/".$param;
     }
     else{
       echo $param;
       return "Home/".$param;
     }
   ```

   };

this logic is much better as it is generic and I don't have to create new routes every time for new method inside the controller.

It is working fine for the client controller which is **Home** but I have another controller named as **Admin** and I want to redirect Admin requests to the Admin controller and Home request to the Home Controller.

Why does above code work fine for the Home controller but returns

> not found

when I validate for the Admin controller?

I am using CI version 3.x

Comment: The Admin routing works if you have the word 'Admin' in your $param. Like `AdminDashboard` would route to `Admin/AdminDashboard` and you'd need an `AdminDashboard()` function in the Admin controller.

Comment: @ourmandave awesome man sorry for the late reply i never thought it was a logical issue your answer did the trick can you please paste this as an asnwer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get crazy, you could parse the methods from the controller file and programatically create the "static" approach.

Pseudo code here

```
$controller_file_contents = file_get_contents('path/to/controller.php');
$controller_methods = function_that_parses_methods_from_file($controller_file_contents);
foreach ($controller_methods as $controller_method) {
    $route[$controller_method] = "Home/" . $controller_method;
}
```

How `function_that_parses_methods_from_file` works is probably gonna involve a regex, something like `function \w+`. If you go with this approach, try to keep the controller as small as possible by offloading as much logic as possible into models, which is often a good idea anyways. That way the performance impact in the router is as small as possible.

Alternatively, you may be able to parse the controller using [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) if you can figure out how to load the controller into memory inside the router without conflicting when you need to load the controller using the router or causing too much performance issues.

Pretty goofy, but every method you create in that controller will automatically create a route.

Comment: you can use [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-class-methods.php) to make it easy

Comment: @elddenmedio Great idea, but how to load the controller class inside of router.php?

Comment: i was gonna ask the same question

Comment: @uneebmeer you might have to load the class into memory, which may be better or worse for performance than a regex type of parsing. Also might be tricky because later you need to load it into memory again to actually run the logic.

Comment: that doesnt look like a good solution to me its better if we can handle it though code using memory always creates chances of error, and it is not a good approach for medium or large scale applications, and mine is a medium scale application

Comment: @uneebmeer If you're controller isn't some overly massive file, I think a regex parsing approach may be better than trying to use get_class_methods. If you go with a regex approach, try to keep the controller as small as possible by offloading as much logic as possible into models, which is usually a good idea anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your menu(url´s) from db like

```
tbl_menu               tbl_level
----------             -------------
id                     id
fk_level               level
name                   dateUP
dateUP                 active
active
```

In your controllers you need to call the correct menu by session or wherever you want

then you can has this in your route.php

```
$route['(.+)'] = 'int_rout/routing/' . json_encode($1);
```

in your controller Int_rout.php

```
public function routing ( $param ) {
    $routing = json_decode($param);
    $routing = explode('/', $routing);

    //$menu -> get menu from model
    foreach($menu as $item){
        if($routing[0] === $item->name){
            //$level -> get level from model
            $redirect = $level->level;
        }
    }

    //the final redirect will be like
    //admin/user or admin/user/12
    //public/us
    $params = ( empty($routing[1])) ? '' : '/' . $routing[1];
    redirect($redirect . '/' . $routing[0] . $params, 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: that is a really long way of doing something simple can we adjust my route somehow according to requirements?

Comment: Maybe it's long but at the same time it is the shortest for what you want, since your solutions don't satisfy you, by this way you only have to add the name in the table menu and it´s level so that it redirects you to the method that do you create in admin or in public controller